# How do I the second argument to the each value in the first argument in an array?

Tags: arrays, for-loop

I am trying to add n to each number in arr.  This is how far I got, any tips would be greatly appreciated!

```
function addN(arr, n){
    for(let i = 0; i < addN.length; i++) {
   return arr[i]+n;
    } 
}
// Uncomment these to check your work!
console.log(addN([1, 2, 3], 3)); // expected log [4, 5, 6]
console.log(addN([3, 4, 5], 2)); // expected log [5, 6, 7]
```

The results I am getting is only adding the second argument to the first value in the first array.  I am getting [4] when I need to be getting [4, 5, 6].

Comment: `addN.length` should be `arr.length`, and you need to push the new values to an array and then return that array after the `for` loop completes. Or just use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: for(let i = 0; i < addN.length; i++) {
   arr[i]+n;
    }
return arr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do:

```
function addN(arr, n){
   for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
       arr[i]+=n;
   }
   return arr;
}
```

Comment: The first and second value of arr are adding n, but not the third, [4, 5, 3] and [5, 6, 5]

Comment: Corrected the code, you should use the length property of arr not of the function